# Python error - bound method Series.map of

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes that store some employee details as below:

DF1 has employee's personal details whereas DF2 store which team they belong to.

**DF1**:

```
emp_id,name
1,Tom
2,Scott
```

**DF2**:

```
emp_id,team_name
1,Finance
2,IT
```

I am trying to merge both these Dataframes using the below function by adding a new column called '***team_name***' in DF1:

```
DF1['team_name'] = DF1['emp_id'].map(DF2.set_index('emp_id')['team_name'])
```

I however get the below error on executing the above code.

```
<bound method Series.map of 0                            ... this has all emp_ids listed
```

Could anyone help me figure how to overcome this error. Thanks

**Update**:

This is the complete sequence that I am doing:

```
DF2_updated = DF2.reset_index()
DF1['team_name'] = DF1['emp_id'].map(DF2.set_index('emp_id')['team_name'])
Final_DF = DF1[DF1['emp_id'].notnull() == True].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This throws this message and I am not sure how to get past this.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. Are you actually getting an exception? If so, can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: @glibdud, I have edited a few more steps that I am performing before getting this message.

Comment: If you want to concat the 2 DataFrames by `emp_id` you can use `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` or pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True) that perform something like an inner join

Comment: @e.arbitrio, thanks for the advice but the problem in that approach is the Dataframe has few other columns that I do not want to it to be part of the Final DF. Is there any way I could only select few columns from a list of columns. Because wne I tried doing an inner join I got a few more columns that expected.

Comment: You can use `.loc` to select the specific columns with all rows and then pull that. An example is below:

`pandas.merge(df1, df2.iloc[:, [0:5]], how='left or inner or ....', on='your_key')`